# Array summary ( working code), not grasping a line of code

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, summarization

Learning arrays atm (self-thought noob)
Can somebody explain what does this part of the code mean here?

```
for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
 ++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];
```

I can't grasp the logic of it. Obviously "answer" is my counter.frequency is increasing by 1 until it reaches array #11 ( which is number 10), but what happens inside the brackets is what baffles me. 
But if it reaches the maximum number of 10, results (which are right) give actual frequency. My guess is this piece of code is what manipulates big part of this class.
I have built on this code, but I am using this part of the code by default (because it's given in the book per se).

Thank you.

Here's the full code

```
public class StudentPoll
{
  public static void main( String[] args)
  {
   int[] responses = {1, 2, 6, 4, 8, 5, 9, 7, 8, 10, 1, 6, 3, 8, 6,
       10, 3, 8, 2, 7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 8, 6, 7, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 6,
       4, 8, 6, 8, 10};
   int[] frequency = new int[ 11 ];

   for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
     ++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];

   System.out.printf( "%s%10s\n", "Rating", "Frequency" );

   for ( int rating = 1; rating < frequency.length; rating++ )
    System.out.printf( "%d%10d\n", rating, frequency[ rating ] );

   }
 }
```

Comment: voting to reopen. The question is very clear, and may just be about an explanation of the syntax used. Even if it is more broad, it is not "about seeking debugging help".

Comment: I think this is one of the few cases where a question asking for code explanation is not too broad, as the OP describes specifically what they do and don't understand fairly clearly. I don't think it should remain closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices of `frequency` correspond to the number being counted, and the value at one of those indices is the frequency of that number. It works because the maximum number in `responses` is `10`, and the length of `frequency` is `11`, meaning that `10` is a valid index into `frequency` (the maximum index of an array is always *array length - 1*).

```
           two 1's   seven 2's
                |    |
                v    v
values:  [ 0 ][ 2 ][ 7 ] ... and so on
indices:   0    1    2
```

You can think of `++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];` as "increase the frequency corresponding to this response by one".

I would find this to be more readable, as it removes the unnecessary `responses[answer]` noise:

```
for (int response : responses)
    frequency[response]++;
```

"For each response, increment the response's frequency by one"

Comment: Excellent suggestion to remove the noise of the explicit array iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I understand the breakdown now of this peace.
++frequency should be "under" [ responses[ answer ] ]
and it goes from 0..10
responses follow an array from response #1....#40

I think what confused me as well in this example is the word "frequency" which I thought may have been a reserved word for a function...

Answer (score 0):

What that line does is increment the value of that particular item in the frequency array.

So let's look and see if answer is 2, then response[2] = 6, and thus you increase the count of frequency[6], if it was 0, then it's now one.

The brackets themselves point to which part of the array that item is in, with count starting from 0.

Like so:

```
int [] array = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

array[0] is 1, 1 is the item at index 0 of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ ) {
 frequency[ responses[ answer ] ] = frequency[ responses[ answer ] ] + 1;
}
```

or even:

```
for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ ) {
 int freqIndex = responses[ answer ];
 frequency[ freqIndex ] = frequency[ freqIndex ] + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int answer = 0; answer < responses.length; answer++ )
    ++frequency[ responses[ answer ] ];
```

Loop starting at zero, while answer is less than the length of the responses array, incrementing by one.

Inside the loop, increment the frequency element indexed by the answer'th response.